# Installing Miniconda3 and subsequently creating environment doesn't recognize conda

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, conda

I've created an executable installer using python's subprocess wherein it first does a silent install of miniconda3 and then creates environments from respective YAML files.

Now, After running and after installation is completed, while creating envs it cannot recognize conda right away.
Error Shown: Conda is not recognized as an internal or external command.

After running the installer again, there is no issue as such. Conda command works and Env is created. Basically, conda command is not recognized when run subsequently to the miniconda3 installation. Please help to resolve this via some means that I'm unaware of.

I've tried:

1. Python Subprocess.run's Shell=True.
2. Restaring script using os.execv
3. Refreshing env variables using chocolatey by adding 'refreshenv' mid-script

OS - Windows 10

Command used for silent miniconda3 -

```
start /wait "" Miniconda3.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /RegisterPython=0 /AddToPath=1 /S /D=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
```

Command for creating env -

```
conda env create --file env_configs/test_env.yaml
```

Thanks for going through this post. Any help would be appreciated.